# What's the code for this graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, tikz-graphs

How can I draw the picture below using tex code? I know that possibly every pic of this type can be made into tex environment, but I'm running out of time and I really appreciate your help. All 7 vertices form a regular heptagon (and hence all lying on the same circumference, for blue arrows). Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: This is not  how the site works. Questions should be about specific parts of a problem that you're having difficulty with, along with a sample document showing what you've tried.  (The simplest code would be `\includegraphics{yourimageofthediagram}`).

Comment: Slide to unlock -> Camera -> Take picture -> Camera Roll

Comment: I didn't test it. I have a samsung machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a starting point:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \n in {0,...,6} {
 \node at ({(360/7*\n)-90}:1) (n\n) {\n};
}

\foreach \n [count = \i] in {0,...,5} {
 \draw[->,blue] (n\n) to[bend right=10] (n\i);
}
\draw[->,blue] (n6) to[bend right=10] (n0);

\draw[->,red] (n0) to[out=240,in=300,distance=20] (n0);
\foreach \x/\y in {3/2,4/5} {
 \draw[->,red] (n\x) to[out={360/7*\x-90},in={360/7*\y-90},distance=20] (n\y);
}
\foreach \x/\y in {1/3,6/4} {
 \draw[->,red] (n\x) to[out={360/7*\x+90},in={360/7*\y+90},distance=10] (n\y);
}
\foreach \x/\y in {5/1,2/6} {
 \draw[->,red] (n\x) to[out={360/7*\x+90},in={360/7*\y+90},distance=10] (n\y);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I’m looking forward to improvements of this code :)

[image]